# Non-static form action without javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a `<form>` with an `action` attribute.

I would like to change the value of `action` based on the value of an `<input>`.

The value is provided by the user. If the value is *page1.php*, the form will be submitted to *page1.php*. If the value is *page2.php*, the form will be submitted to *page2.php*, and so on.

Right now I'm achieving this using JavaScript, however it doesn't work on a browser with JavaScript disabled.

Is there any way to make the `action` non-static without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to receive the value on the server side, than using `get` as the form's `method` will work (you end up with `page.php?my_var_name=my_var_value`).

If, however, you want to direct the form to a **completely different page based on the value** of your input, you'll either have to use JS, or have a "catchall" page on the server side that gets the form and redirects to the final page based on the value.

Comment: looks like its not possible then

Comment: Why not? Could you elaborate on what you need? In my experience, there's a solution to every problem :)

Comment: Then in the PHP page you'll have to parse the URL and redirect to another page (or run a different function in the same page) based on the text in the query string. Another way to treat this is use a hash URL (i.e. domain.com/#myhash) which may take you to a different part of a page, or a different form.

Comment: I don't have curl, simply a server-side URL redirect would not suffice. It must be a *redirected POST*.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without invoking any javascript at all.

PHP example;

```
<?php
/*if no destination was set previously the form will post back to itself*/ 
$action=isset($_Request['destination'])?$_Request['destination']:'';
?>
<form name='a-form-name' action="<?php echo $action;?>">

/*include other inputs etc as required.
Include a 'destination' input in _all_ forms involved.
You can of course name it whatever you like.  But should always be the same name in all forms involved.
*/

<input type='hidden' name='destination' value='the-desired-destination-of-next-action'>

<input type='submit' name='whatever' value='Click here'>
</form>
```

When you press the submit button it will go to whatever destination you set in the previous submission or 'destination' in the url query string.

You can even make the destination hidden input's value dynamic by using a variable instead if need be.  Branching can be quite easy and extensive using this method.
HTH

Comment: This doesn't work, the problem is that `input.value` is provided by the user, and thus not known beforehand.